# Trying to take some data from my file called "listing-card" which is is saved in the component folder

Tags: laravel-9

```
@foreach($listings as $listing)
<x-listing-card :listing="$listings" />
@endforeach
```

the listing card is in the component file

I was expecting to get results from 'listing-card' blade file. but I got this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVo3L.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without a better understanding of your code, the first thing I see is the `:listing=$listings`

I would think you would want the individual item $listing from your foreach.

Secondly, The error states it can not find the class.  Be wary of kabob-case vs CamelCase.  It has bitten me a few times

Edit/Update addressing comment below:

You will have to go and look at your component blade file to check on your exact naming convention you are using. For example you have a class named SiteInfo and in the render section you would have it return something like : `return view('components/site-info');`
Your file and class being used will be SiteInfo.blade.php and the class in it will be: `class SiteInfo extends Component`

```
example: 
@foreach($listings as $listing)
<x-listing-card :listing="$listing" />
@endforeach
```

Your Class file would be something similar to:

```
class Listing-card extends Component
{
    public $listing;
 }
/**
 * Create a new component instance.
 *
 *
 */
 public function __construct($listing)
     {
     $this->listing = $listing;
   
     }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
     public function render()
    {
        return view('components.listing-card');
    }
```

}

You might have to enable some logging at key points in your app and pull data.  The laravel log /storage/logs/laravel.log is invaluable in find your mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes i want the individual item from the foreach but to have a better picture, can you suggest what to write in the class? thank you